# warning: passing argument 1 of '...' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, pointers

So, the objective of this code (or at least this part of the code) was that i would input the info of people in "cadastra", then show all the info of those people with "mostra". I tried using pointers, since i can't do anything to the main function (teacher's instructions) but it just doesn't work for some reason, pointers are still an enigma to me. I tried looking into other posts with this same "passing argument 1..." problem, but they didn't really help me since the problem seemed to be slightly different there.
I end up getting the "***warning: passing argument 1 of '...' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]***" in cadastra, mostra and mostra1 inside the menu function.
(i haven't started mostra1's code yet cuz i wanted to solve this problem before going there, so you can ignore it.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct prof {
    char nome[50];
    char matricula[50];
    char email[50];
    int ativo;
    int dia, mes, ano, hora, min;
};

void cadastro(struct prof *P[100]) {
    char nome1[50];
    char matricula1[50];
    char email1[50];
    int ativo, exit;
    int dia1, mes1, ano1, hora1, min1, last = 0;

    do {
        printf("\n----------------");
        printf("\n1- Digite seu Nome: ");
        scanf("%s", nome1);
        getchar();

        printf("\n2- Digite seu email (exemplo@ufu.br): ");
        scanf("%s", email1);
        getchar();

        printf("\n3- Digite sua matricula: ");
        scanf("%s", matricula1);
        getchar();

        printf("\n4- Data (dia mes ano): ");
        scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
        getchar();


        printf("\n5- Horario (hora minutos): ");
        scanf("%d:%d", &hora1, &min1);
        getchar();
        printf("----------------\n");

        for (int i = last; i < last + 1; i++) {
            if (P[i] -> ativo == 0) {
                P[i] -> dia = dia1;
                P[i] -> mes = mes1;
                P[i] -> ano = ano1;
                P[i] -> hora = hora1;
                P[i] -> min = min1;
                P[i] -> ativo = 1;
                strcpy(P[i] -> nome, nome1);
                strcpy(P[i] -> matricula, matricula1);
                strcpy(P[i] -> email, email1);
                last++;
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("\n\n1- Continuar\n0 - Sair\n");
        printf("\nDigite opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &exit);
    } while (exit != 0);
}

void mostra(struct prof *P[100]) {
    system("cls");

    int exit;
    printf("\nLista de reservas\n");

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            if (P[i] -> ativo == 1) {
                printf("----------------\n");
                printf("1- Nome: %s\n", P[i] -> nome);
                printf("2- E-mail: %s\n", P[i] -> email);
                printf("3- Matricula: %s\n", P[i] -> matricula);
                printf("4- Data: %d/%d/%d\n", P[i] -> dia, P[i] -> mes, P[i] -> ano);
                printf("5- Hora: %d:%d\n", P[i] -> hora, P[i] -> min);
                printf("----------------\n");
            }
            printf("\n1- Continuar\n0 - Sair\n");
            printf("\nDigite opcao: ");
            scanf("%d", &exit);
            getchar();
        }
    } while (exit != 0);
}

void mostra1(struct prof P[100]) {

}

void menu() {
    int opcao;
    struct prof P[100];

    while (1) {
        printf("\nBem vindo ao Sistema de Sistema de Informacao para controle das reservas dos laboratorios e salas da UFU\n");
        printf("\n1- Cadastrar ");
        printf("\n2- Mostrar Todos");
        printf("\n3- Mostrar um");
        printf("\n9- Sair ");
        printf("\nDigite opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);

        if (opcao == 1) cadastro(&P);
        if (opcao == 2) mostra(&P);
        if (opcao == 3) mostra1(&P);
        if (opcao == 9) return;
    }
}

int main() {
    menu();
}
```

Comment: in the declaration of functions `cadastro` and `mostra`, try removing the asterisk in the argument, so `struct prof P[100]` instead of `struct prof *P[100]`, like for function `mostra1`. Right now, those two functions expect an array of pointers to struct, not an array of structs

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Though i'm still getting the "passing argument 1 of '...' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" warning...

Comment: at which line are you getting the error?

Comment: oh wait, inside the `menu()` function, ok so, in the 4 `if`s, remove the `&` when calling the different functions. an array variable is by definition already a pointer, so you don't need to pass its address to work on the array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages, but also read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Answer (score 2):

`void mostra(struct prof *P[100])` expects an *array of 100 pointers to `struct prof`*. What you are passing is *a pointer to an array of `struct prof`* (`monstra(&P)`). The difference is subtle, but very meaningful.

Instead of either of these options, change the calls to `cadastro`, `monstra`, and `monstra1` to pass the array

```
mostra(P)
```

and change the functions to simply accept an array (which actually decays to a pointer to the first element of the array)

```
void mostra(struct prof P[100])
```

Not that you must change your [member access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) from *member access through pointer* (`->`) to *member access* (`.`), as the array contains structure elements not pointers to structures.

Another issue is that you are utilizing the values found in `P[i].ativo` without ever initializing them. You should either *zero out* the array, or decide on a way to default initialize the structures it contains.

```
struct prof P[100];        
memset(P, 0, sizeof P);
```

Yet another issue is you are exposing yourself to buffer overflows by not limiting the amount of characters you read. If you are going to use `scanf` to fill

```
char nome1[50];
```

you should limit it to reading a maximum of the size minus one (which leaves room for the NUL character)

```
scanf("%49s", nome1);
```

It would also be a good idea to check the return values of your `scanf` functions as they indicate the amount of *conversions* that successfully took place. Without checking this, you are possibly operating on incomplete, uninitialized, or otherwise garbage data.

Additionally, in `cadastro` the local variable `ativo` is unused, and the looping logic in that function has the potential to run outside the bounds of your array. `last` may eventually be  `>= 100`.

---

Side note, using `exit` as a variable name could lead to confusion. While it is perfectly legal to shadow identifiers, [`exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) is an extremely well known standard library function. At a glace, reading `scanf("%d", &exit);` is very confusing. This is purely stylistic, but you may want to avoid this in the future.

Finally, `void main()` is strictly wrong. `main` has two valid signatures: `int main(int, char **)` or `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is basically a memory adress that points to something, it could be an int, an array of ints (which is a pointer too!) or anything.
lets see an example

```c
    int* p = malloc(50); //Allocate 50 bytes for this pointer
    int P[50];           //Create an array of 50 ints;
    p[0] = 20;           //The pointer is an array too!
    P[0] = 20;
    printf("p[0] = %d\n",p[0]); //Output: p[0] = 20
    printf("P[0] = %d\n",P[0]); //Output p[0] = 20

    printf("Adress of p: %p\n",&p); //Output (depends on every computer and every run): 0x7ffceb5e2ba8
    printf("Adress of P: %p\n",&P); //Output: 0x7ffceb5e2bb0
```

So basically when you do `struct prof* P[100]` this is an array of pointer to prof structures.
But in your menu() function you are creating just a `struct prof P[100]` and then passing &P to your function, which is OK because &P its a memory adress to your structure, but c is throwing a warning to you, this is not an error, just a warning.
It would be more natural if you just create a `struct prof* P[100]` and then pass it to the function as `cadastra(P)`.
Then you have plenty of errors in your code (e.g you are not asking for input for `ativo` but you are using it in a conditional)